# JQuery each append and fadeIn one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an each function on an array and I want to create a div for each array row and fade them in sequentially. Preferably how they are ordered in the array. Currently I manage to fade all in at once, but I want it sequentially. This is my code:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var generatedDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));

    generatedDiv.attr('id',"div-"+val.id);
    generatedDiv.css({//somecssproperties});
    $('#results').append(generatedDiv);
    generatedDiv.fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you created a fiddle of this, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code

```
var t = 100;
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    var generatedDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
    generatedDiv.attr('id',"div-"+val.id);
    generatedDiv.css({//somecssproperties});
    $('#results').append(generatedDiv);
    t += 100;
    generatedDiv.delay(t).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfuvn/7/)

Comment: I guess this will start the `fadeIn`s at the same moment, only making the following ones slower.

Comment: thanks. but not entirely doing what I want, the latter ones are just loading a bit slower than the first one, but they are still loaded all at once.

Comment: oh, now I am seeing the new change. lemme give it a try

Comment: @genesis-fi, you don't need to increment `t` anymore - otherwise the later would be bloody slow.

Comment: @cbrandolino he wants them to show one by one, not all in one moment/all after 100 ms

Comment: @genesis-φ, you're right. I tought `.delay()` influenced `.each()` as well.